# Edit operation failing in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This is my code:

```
router.post('/update-posting', (req, res, next) => {
    Account.findById(req.user._id)
        .then(doc => {
            var type = [];
            if (req.body.full !== undefined) {
                type.push('full');
            }
            if (req.body.part !== undefined) {
                type.push('part');
            }
            if (req.body.seasonal !== undefined) {
                type.push('seasonal');
            }
            if (req.body.temporary !== undefined) {
                type.push('temp');
            }
            var title = req.body.title;
            var salary = req.body.salary;
            var timeline = req.body.timeline;
            var experience = req.body.experience;
            var description = req.body.description;
            var duties = req.body.duties;
            doc.postings[req.body._id] = {
                _id: req.body._id,
                title: title,
                type: type,
                salary: salary,
                timeline: timeline,
                description: description,
                duties: duties,
                experience: experience,
            };
            doc.save(r=>console.log(r));
        })
        .then(() => res.redirect('/employer/booth-edit'))
        .catch(e => console.log(e))
});
```

And here's the model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var plm = require('passport-local-mongoose');
var accountSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    // username (comes with passport): email; -> just for reference.
    accType: String,
    fullName: String,
    displayName: String,
    companyName: String,
    contactPersonFullName: String,
    companyWebsite: String,
    city: String,
    province: String,
    postalCode: String,
    phoneNumber: String,
    hiringRegion: [], // TODO
    description: String,
    logo: [],
    workingWithEOESC: Boolean,
    industry: String,
    phone: String,
    ageGroup: String,
    education: String,
    lookingForWork: String,
    employmentStatus: String,
    resume: [],
    mainWorkExp: String,
    boothVisits: Number,
    postings: []
});
accountSchema.plugin(plm);
module.exports = mongoose.model('account', accountSchema);
```

What I'm doing is trying to update an object in the postings array. Now here's the weird part. When I console log the result ***before*** `doc.save()` I get the updated version... And when I console log the response from `doc.save()` I get null... I'm sure that's a small bug but I cannot see it anywhere.

All fields are coming from the `req.body` object correctly.

Here are the logs.

Original object:

```
{ _id: 0,
    title: 'Web developer',
    type: [ 'full', 'seasonal' ],
    salary: '14$',
    timeline: '3 months',
    description: 'tada',
    duties: 'tada',
    experience: '5 years' }
```

Updated object:

```
{ _id: '0',
    title: 'Car mechanic',
    type: [ 'part', 'temp' ],
    salary: '50$',
    timeline: '2 weeks',
    description: 'desc',
    duties: 'resp',
    experience: '4 years' }
```

`doc.save()` response:

```
null
```

What's more interesting, this is the code I'm using for "creating" a job posting. It's almost the same code, and it works perfectly well:

```
router.route('/add-posting')
    .get((req, res, next) => {
        res.render('users/employer/add-posting', {
            title: 'Employer Booth - Add Job Posting',
            user: req.user
        });
    })
    .post((req, res, next) => {
        // Determining type of work.
        var type = [];
        if (req.body.full !== undefined) {
            type.push('full');
        }
        if (req.body.part !== undefined) {
            type.push('part');
        }
        if (req.body.seasonal !== undefined) {
            type.push('seasonal');
        }
        if (req.body.temporary !== undefined) {
            type.push('temp');
        }
        var title = req.body.title;
        var salary = req.body.salary;
        var timeline = req.body.timeline;
        var experience = req.body.experience;
        var description = req.body.description;
        var duties = req.body.duties;

        Account.findById(req.user._id)
            .then(doc => {
                doc.postings.push({
                    _id: doc.postings.length,
                    title: title,
                    type: type,
                    salary: salary,
                    timeline: timeline,
                    description: description,
                    duties: duties,
                    experience: experience,
                });
                doc.save();
            })
            .then(() => res.redirect('/employer/booth-edit'))
            .catch(e => console.log(e));
    });
```

Comment: I think your issue here may be that you are using the wrong operation. You are finding an object in your database, and then doing some operations to manipulate the data, and then trying to save that "new" document. The problem is the `doc.save` call will fail because the `_id` field must be unique. Your database doesn't know that you are trying to update an existing document. It thinks you are trying to insert a new one.  I think the database operation you should use here is `findOneAndUpdate`.

Comment: That's weird, because I'm using `doc.save()` for pushing to an array, which works perfectly well. I'll update my question

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Sorry about that. I haven't used mongoose in a while so I misremembered how the `#save` method works.

Comment: No problem, you at least tried to help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They way you're doing it may work. But mongo has already provided you with `update` or `findOneAndupdate` methods. I'd suggest you to use them.

Your query would be easy to understand and debug when needed.

Try something like

```
db.collection.update({_id: .user._id},{$push :{postings:  yourObject}})
```

Answer (score 0):

I just remembered I had this issue before. Turns out that to update an array we need to do this:

```
doc.postings.set(req.body._id, {
    _id: req.body._id,
    title: title,
    type: type,
    salary: salary,
    timeline: timeline,
    description: description,
    duties: duties,
    experience: experience,
});
```

I remember reading an issue on that. Will add the link if I find it again.

We need to use the .set method instead of the = operator.